# 128bit texture in openGL does not display (black screen)

Tags: opengl, textures, 128-bit

I create the texture like this:

```
GLuint PingPongShader::GenerateTexture()
{

float* pixels = new float[width*height * 4];
for(int i = 0; i < width * height; i+=4)
{
    pixels[i] = 1.0;
    pixels[i+1] = 1.0;
    pixels[i+2] = 1.0;
    pixels[i+3] = 1.0;
}
GLuint t;
glGenTextures(1, &t);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, t);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_BASE_LEVEL, 0);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAX_LEVEL, 0);
glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA32F, width, height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_FLOAT, pixels);
delete[] pixels;
LogGLError();
return t;
}
```

My display function looks like this:

```
void display()
{
    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    shader.BindCurrentTexture();
    shader.EnableShader();
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    {
        glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 0.0f);
        glVertex2f(-1.0f, -1.0f);

        glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 0.0f);
        glVertex2f(1.0f, -1.0f);

        glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 1.0f);
        glVertex2f(1.0f, 1.0f);

        glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 1.0f);
        glVertex2f(-1.0f, 1.0f);

    }
    shader.DisableShader();
    glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glutSwapBuffers();
}
```

The shader looks like this:
Vertex:

```
varying vec2 texture_coordinate;

void main()
{
    // Transforming The Vertex
    gl_Position = gl_ModelViewProjectionMatrix * gl_Vertex;

    // Passing The Texture Coordinate Of Texture Unit 0 To The Fragment Shader
    texture_coordinate = vec2(gl_MultiTexCoord0);
}
```

Fragment:

```
varying vec2 texture_coordinate; 
uniform sampler2D my_color_texture;

void main()
{
    // Sampling The Texture And Passing It To The Frame Buffer
    gl_FragColor = texture2D(my_color_texture, texture_coordinate);
}
```

Somehow I'm only getting a black screen, even though the pixels are all 1.0 (white). I don't see where the problem is :/

Comment: why you are using shaders with fixed function pipeline?

Comment: because I will use a custom fragment shader later.

Comment: what version of OpenGL context do you have?

Comment: I'm not sure, where can I look that up ? I'm not getting glErrors though. (shader compiles fine too)

Comment: `glGetString​(GL_VERSION​);`

Answer (score 0):

You are writing code using deprecated functions. In OpenGL 4.4 you can't use `glBegin()` and friends. Please use `VBO` for vertex and texture coordinate data. You can look it up in a modern OpenGL tutorial. You can also request older OpenGL context using `glutInitContextVersion()`. Make sure to use OpenGL 2.1 or enable complitability profile for versions > 3.0.

Comment: Sure I can. I just forgot to call glEnd(). Derp ~.~